# Titanium sqlite database search

Tags: javascript, arrays, sqlite, titanium

How can i create a a button or drop down menu that sorts my database, by alphabetical order, newest to oldest. etc. I assume you can do `Array.reverse();` for the newest to oldest but how can you toggle this so it turns on and off, and `Arrays.sort();` does it alphabetically. but again there is the problem of turning it on and off.

Comment: I don't understand, you like to sort at database query or you like to work with arrays?

Comment: @developer82 sorry for not being specific, i wish to sort a database query.

Comment: ok. say your select query is "select * from users" and you would like to sort by username you'll write "select * from users order by username"

Comment: This is already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26589127/titanium-sqlite-order-by-statement)!