# Titanium sqlite ORDER BY statement

Tags: javascript, sqlite, titanium, appcelerator

Using Titanium appcelerator. How can i sort my database with an sql query which is activated on a button click.  my code so far is:

```
SortButton.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    sortList();
});


function sortList()
{
    db.execute("SELECT * FROM SavedList ORDER BY SavedListed ASC");
}
```

Comment: Show the code that puts the data into the list.

Comment: why do you want to sort the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code :    db.execute("SELECT * FROM SavedList ORDER BY SavedListed ASC");    is correct. Just open database before db.execute and close it after db.execute. It will work.

To open database :
    var db = Ti.Database.open('databaseName');

To close database:
    db.close();